# About SQL CE and indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

i have a  question that i hope someone can answer. I`m making a application that need a database and since the target of this application is the regular user i want to make it simple for the user so he does not have to think about installing databases and etc.

So i decided to use SQL CE but as i saw it does not support indexes. So my question is how big may the database become before it queries start taking alot of time. The application shoud make between 500 and 3000 new records a day in a single tabale and no more then 5-20 records in 2 other tables.

So for how long you guys think it is going to work good and when it shall start making problems. And if you have any idea of alternative aproach please let me know.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Compact supports both unique and non-unique indexes. What makes you think it does not?